# Is it possible to programatically preload a shared library?

Tags: android, dynamic-linking, dlopen, ld-preload, android-native-library

Im building a project that needs to modify the behavior of some bionic methods (e.g getaddrinfo, __android_print). I've been able to create the hooked library both using a standalone compiler or including it directly in the Apk using Cmake. I've been able to preload the shared library using setprop wrap.com.foo.bar and LD_PRELOAD, and it is working and I get the result I want. However, I want to preload the hooked library programatically so I dont need to go through the specific steps of LD_PRELOAD (a.k.a disable SELinux, root device, setprop), every time after rebooting a device.

I tried using

```
// MainActivity
companion object {
   System.load("/data/data/com.foo.bar/lib/libhookedmethod.so")
}
```

But I don't see the method being replaced.

As a reference, the hooked method is rather simple. Here's an extreme simplification:

```
int __android_print(varargs a) {
   int realmethod(...);
   realmethod = dlsym("__android_print");
   doStuff();
   int res = realmethod(a) ;
   return res;
}
```

Again, compiling and using LD_PRELOAD works, but I want to achieve it without using LD_PRELOAD...
Anything helps! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `LD_PRELOAD` works by asking the dynamic loader to load referenced library *before* any other. The loader *resolves* references to a given symbol by searching loaded libraries in their load order.

Once a symbol is resolved to a particular library, it will not be rebound to some other library for the duration of this process.

Above explanation should make it obvious why loading `libhookedmethod.so` *after* the program is already running has no effect.

About the only way you can achieve what you want is to `setenv()` (if not already set) and re-`exec()` the current process. Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *e = getenv("LD_PRELOAD");
  if (e == NULL || /* any other checks that show LD_PRELOAD to not be as we want it */) {
    setenv("LD_PRELOAD", ..., 1);
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
  }
  // LD_PRELOAD is to our liking. Run the actual program.
  ...
}
```